# How do I target only the first span?

Tags: css, css-selectors, dropdown, jquery-select2, html-select

I'm having an issue with [select2](https://select2.org/) where the original select span text still appears on the page (`<span>Large</span>` in the below example). To target this I have tried:

```
.select-option-ui span:first-of-type {
   display: none;
}
```

Weirdly this hides both `<span>Large</span>` and the span further down (highlighted in the below image) which is the one which needs to stay. I need a way to work around this and remove the first span only, CSS or jS/jQuery options are all okay.

[image: Example]

Interested in solutions as well as whether this is a known bug with select2?

Answer (score 0):

**RE a workaround, working with jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".select-option-ui").children(":first").remove();
});
```

Comment: Regarding downvotes: You showed an image of code - [which you should not do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1427878), and you did not present a proper [mre] of the issue either.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for confirming will ensure I bear that in mind in future :)